# EMWIN Keil LCD display shows half the screen completely!

Tags: pic, pixels

I have written one project in Keil for STM32F103RE && ILI9325 2.8" TFT LCD,
So my problem is this, the `GUI_SetBkColor(GUI_BLUE);` Function only fill only half of LCD Screen like this:

[image: LCD PIC]

as you can see the string is `"www.keil.com"` but it have been duplicated in lcd and uncleear to read, and only fill only half of LCD Screen hase been colored.

the defult lCD Pixels is 320x240 and i have setted that in my files,like this pic:

[image]

The could could be found here:

[Source code via keil](https://www.4shared.com/s/fwQEsG6kbda)

> Update:
>
> with doubling the x&y Pixels (640x480) it became this kind:

[image: (640x480)]

So what do you think about that?!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please remove the second picture and post the actual code text instead

Comment: just a guess ..... try setting your screen size to 240x320     ...... is there a setting for screen orientation?

Comment: the orientation change but still half screen!!

Comment: what happens if you double one of the dimensions? .... try 480x320 or 320x480

Comment: by doubling its go to 3/4 of the screen but by 1800x2000 pixel and it covers all of the pages.

Comment: interesting .... if i am not mistaken, the 1800x2000 is the `virtual size` ...... the 320x240 is the `physical size`  ..... there may be a configuration setting for that